# How to execute git command through Django migration?

Tags: django, git, django-migrations

I have the requirement to execute a git command in a Django migration. I need to clear the contents of a directory via a Django migration because we do not have access to the production server directly. Being new to both Django and git, I have no idea of how this could be achieved. Any help would be highly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

you can create [data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) migration which will have function to execute logic.
second thing required is some python git [library](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/) to write logic.